# MySQL как получить количество записей из разных таблиц одним запросом?

Tags: php, mysql

Приведу пример. Есть у меня таблицы:

> category - id,iso
>
> teasers - id,category_id

Мне нужно передать параметр iso например ru и вывести сумму всех тизеров во всех категориях которая содержит запись как iso=ru

Я бы это сделал так:

```
$count = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE iso='ru'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teasers WHERE category_id=".$row['id']))+$count;
}
echo($count);
```

Но, что то мне подсказывает что можно эти лишние действия сделать одной командой. Только не могу сообразить каким образом написать запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM teasers 
WHERE category_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM category
    WHERE iso='ru'
)
```

Или так:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM teasers t
    INNER JOIN category c ON t.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.iso='ru'
```

Если вам нужна сумма (или количество) лучше использовать агрегатные функции `SUM` или `COUNT`.